# Unresolved external symbols- Just after update to vss2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

i'am facing with an big problem.
After update my files to visual studio 2015 i get an unresolved external symbols

This is main function.

```
void SpherePack::LostChild(SpherePack *t)
{
    assert(mChildCount);
    assert(mChildren);

#ifdef _DEBUG  // debug validation code.

    SpherePack *pack = mChildren;
    bool found = false;
    while (pack)
    {
        if (pack == t)
        {
            assert(!found);
            found = true;
        }
        pack = pack->_GetNextSibling();
    }
    assert(found);

#endif

    // first patch old linked list.. his previous now points to his next
    SpherePack *prev = t->_GetPrevSibling();

    if (prev)
    {
        SpherePack *next = t->_GetNextSibling();
        prev->SetNextSibling(next); // my previous now points to my next
        if (next) next->SetPrevSibling(prev);
        // list is patched!
    }
    else
    {
        SpherePack *next = t->_GetNextSibling();
        mChildren = next;
        if (mChildren) mChildren->SetPrevSibling(0);
    }

    mChildCount--;

    if (!mChildCount && HasSpherePackFlag(SPF_SUPERSPHERE))
    {
        mFactory->Remove(this);
    }
}
```

[image: error]

I added an photo with the complet error.
Note: In debug mode all work fine. I don't have this error.
Just in distribute mode.

This issue apper after changed from visual studio 2013 to 2015.
In 2013 all work fine

Comment: Show your SpherePack header and source file.

Comment: @AnonMail Thanks for you answe, I edited main message.

Comment: Could it be that you declare you function inline in the header but it's not defined in the header?  Just a guess.

Comment: In debug mode work fine. Sooo can't be a define/declare problem.

Comment: Please give it a try.  Anything is possible with VS ;)

Comment: Tried.  Same error. :(((((((

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95090/discussion-between-ramy-and-anon-mail).

Comment: Is this in a library? Did you tick you want it as a dependency in your configuration for Release?

Comment: @Aesthete Yes it's a library  http://prntscr.com/92gp6s i have 16 lib. and userinterface is the linker.   http://prntscr.com/92gpsz http://prntscr.com/92gpzw

Comment: Hmm I'm on a mac atm so I'm guessing, but in the dropdown where you choose "Distribute" there should be an option to configure, and you should find a bunch of different configs for debug, release etc. Make sure your lib is ticked for Distribute (otherwise it just won't build, and you'll only have headers - hence the linker error.) Sorry that's all I can help with! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LostChild is declared as inline in SpherePack.h but is defined in SpherePack.cpp, which means it won't be accessible outside it. Now, Unlink (which is inlined in SpherePack.h) calls LostChild; so, if you call Unlink outside SpherePack.cpp (directly or not) you'll have the undefined error for LostChild as a result.

The reason for the error not appearing in debug mode is that inlining is disabled then, so you do have code generated for LostChild in SpherePack.obj.
I don't know why it didn't happen in the previous VS release, but my guess is the same reason. Probably your setup there was such that inlining was disabled.

You can solve this problem by either declaring LostChild as non-inline or moving its implementation from SpherePack.cpp to SpherePack.h